# preventDefault not work in submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `html` form and when I clicked `submit` button page goes to insert.php
I don't wont it 
preventDefoult don't work
I have this `script`
html

**HTML**

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<input  type="text" name="username" placeholder=""><br />
<input  type="text" name="name" placeholder=""><br />
<input  type="text" name="lastname" placeholder=""><br />
<input id="mail" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail"><br />
<input id="mail_1" type="text" placeholder="reply E-mail"><br />
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder=""><br />
<input id="password_1"  type="password" placeholder=""><br /> 
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="registration">
</form>
```

**jquery**

```
$("#submit").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: PHP and MySQL have little to nothing to do with this (tags edited, PHP code removed) – please tag according to the problem in the future, and post only relevant code.

Comment: I get the impression `preventDefault()` does not work on `<button></button>` whose type is _submit_ but _button_

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of listening for the button click you need to listen for `<form>` submit:

```
$("form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

---

Modern jQuery (1.7 or later):

```
$("form").on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just missed the event which is canceling

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
```

});

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the event is bubbling up and the submit event of your form is being called.

Instead of listening the `click` event of your button, you should listen the `submit` event of your form:

```
$("#formId").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

And add the `id` attribute to your form:

```
<form id="formId" ...
```

That should stop your form from working.

Comment: add `id="formId"` to your form

Answer (score 1):

First add an ID to your form, I will use `myFormId`.

```
<form id="myFormId"  action="insert.php" method="post">
    <input  type="text" name="username" placeholder=""><br />
    <input  type="text" name="name" placeholder=""><br />
    <input  type="text" name="lastname" placeholder=""><br />
    <input id="mail" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail"><br />
    <input id="mail_1" type="text" placeholder="reply E-mail"><br />
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder=""><br />
    <input id="password_1"  type="password" placeholder=""><br /> 
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="registration">
</form>
```

Then use the form Id:

```
$('#myFormId').on('click', function (event){ 
     event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: Please explain me `.on` meaning

Answer (score 1):

To any one lurking around here in future, my problem was that, the form didn't load before the script and hence the event was not bound. So I did the following and my issue was solved:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#submit").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ...
        ...
    });
}
```