# why AJAX redirects to the new page in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I have a form:

```
<form class="searchForm">
            <div class="box_style_1">
                <h4><?= Yii::t("common", "Age"); ?></h4>
                <?
                echo '<b class="badge">3</b> ' . Slider::widget([
                        'name'=>'age',
                        'value'=>'250,650',
                        'sliderColor'=>Slider::TYPE_GREY,
                        'pluginOptions'=>[
                            'min'=>3,
                            'max'=>21,
                            'step'=>1,
                            'range'=>true
                        ],
                    ]) . ' <b class="badge">21</b>';
                ?>
                <br /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="searchByAge"/>
                <br /><br />
            </div>
            </form>
```

And want to show the result in console.log:

```
$('.searchByAge').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var range = $('.form-control').val();
var min = range.split(',')[0];
var max = range.split(',')[1];

//alert(min+' '+max);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/age/'+min+'/'+max,
    data: $('.searchForm').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
        console.log(errorMessage); // Optional
    }
});
})
```

and that's my AJAX code. But when I click on Search button it redirects me to the new page and nothing in the console log. I do not know what is wrong in my code.

I return a JSON from the '/age/min_age/max_age' page, but the result shows in the new page.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This should ideally work, try using `$('form').on('submit'..` handler instead of `$('.searchByAge').on('click'`. Here is an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21837273/3639582

Comment: Are you sure your function is running? Try adding an `alert` to see if it's called.

Answer (score 5):

change code to below. change input type `submit` to `button`

```
<input type="button" value="Search" class="searchByAge"/>
```

also wrap your code in `$(document).ready();`

> Make sure to  add jQuery library from correct path.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

     $('.searchByAge').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var range = $('.form-control').val();
        var min = range.split(',')[0];
        var max = range.split(',')[1];

          //alert(min+' '+max);

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/age/'+min+'/'+max,
          data: $('.searchForm').serialize(),
          success: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
            console.log(errorMessage); // Optional
          }
      });
     });  
 });
```

Comment: but `e.preventDefault();` is called in the click handler

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade  `type="button"` will not submit form . check demo have update demo of barmar http://jsfiddle.net/kojvebs7/4/

Comment: @Barmar confirm! i will delete my comment. So I don't understand why it redirects him. It may really be the case that the funciton is not called because of not wrapping into `$(document).ready()`. But this is a guess only.

Comment: I suspect you're right, but he said "it still redirects" after you put `document.ready` in your answer.

Comment: @Barmar  i have add all possible answers for this question.  also added  `Make sure to add jQuery library from correct path.`   to my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

replace your code

```
$('.searchByAge').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
```

with this

```
$('form.searchForm').on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
```

on first code you are preventing your click event instead of submit event thats why form is still submitting